# Нахождение моды в C++. Программа просто крашится

Tags: c++, алгоритм, вектор

Есть тут небольшая программа, которая по идее должна выводить самое часто введённое имя и количество его повторений. Но при выполнении она просто-навсего крашится. Прошу помощи.

```
    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    russian(); //отдельная функция в заголовочном файле, не обращайте внимания
    vector<string> strings; 
    string current = " ";
    string max = " ";
    int nmax = 0;
    int count = 0;
    cout << "Введите последовательность имён ";
    while(cin >> current) {
        strings.push_back(current);
    }
    sort(strings.begin(), strings.end());
    current = " ";
    for(int i = 0; i < strings.size(); ++i){
        if(current == strings[i]) {
            ++count;
        }
        else {
            if(count >= nmax) {
                nmax = count;
                max = strings[i - 1];
            }
            else {
                current = strings[i];
                count = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "\nКоличество повторений: " << nmax << "\nИмя повторяющееся наибольшее количество раз: " << max;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже было правильно замечено, при первой же итерации цикла, когда переменная `i` равна 0,  имеет место обращение к несуществующему элементу вектора

```
max = strings[i - 1]
              ^^^^^^
```

Можно упростить логику программы. Ниже показано, как это сделать, используя вложенный цикл.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v;

    std::string s;

    while (std::cin >> s) v.push_back(s);

    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());

    size_t max_count = 0;
    s.clear();

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); )
    {
        size_t j = i;

        while (i < v.size() && v[i] == v[j]) i++;

        if (max_count < i - j)
        {
            max_count = i - j;
            s = v[j];
        }
    }

    std::cout << s << ": " << max_count << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Программа была бы еще более прозрачной, если вместо вектора использовать стандартный контейнер std::map, который уже включает в себя элементы в упорядочном виде.

Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, size_t> m;

    std::string s;

    while (std::cin >> s) ++m[s];

    auto it = std::max_element( m.begin(), m.end(),
        []( const auto  &max, const auto &current )
        {
            return max.second < current.second;
        });

    std::cout << it->first << ": " << it->second << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас проблема на 1 итерации.

Пусть `i = 0`

```
if(count >= nmax) {
      nmax = count;
      max = strings[i - 1];
                    ^^^^^^ 
}
```

`count = 0, nmax = 0`. Код выполнится. Ну и выход за границы массива.
Проще всего заменить знак `>=` на `>`.